# Refining results of an existing search query in Android

Tags: android, search, cursor, android-contentprovider

In my Android app, I want to execute a query against a content provider, and then refine that search (I have two `WHERE` clause strings). The records that should be returned by the second query are a subset of the rows returned by the first query.

My current solution is like this:

```
Cursor cursor1 = query (myUri, myProjection, where1, null, null);  
//do stuff  
Cursor cursor2 = query (myUri, myProjection, where2, null, null);  
//do other stuff
```

If I do this, the second query run is not very efficient at all (it searches the full database, just like the first). I would like the second query to run only against the rows that are returned in cursor1. Can this be done, and how?

The android documentation states that queries may be cached if I use the same (parameterised) where string, with different parameters. Could this be useful, or is there a totally different way to do it?

Comment: Just for clarification, I am trying to find a solution that does not involve duplicating the data in my own data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Check [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). It implements [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface and contains a few interesting methods: setFilterQueryProvider and getFilterQueryProvider. I haven't used CursorAdapter, but if it is similar to other adapters (or custom adapters implementing Filterable) then it is exactly what you need.

**UPDATE** Here is an example: http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/

The part you are interested in is this:

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            // Search for states whose names begin with the specified letters.
            Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getMatchingStates(
                    (constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));
            return cursor;
        }
    });
```

As it returns new Cursor instance I assume that it does hit DB one more time. You might implement your own search logic by iterating cursor and looking for matches. You will have to write some benchmark to see if it is worth avoiding hitting database with a new Query as by manually iterating Cursor you will be hitting database harder. Remember that you do not actually retrieve data (row/record) from DB unless you explicitly ask for it (by calling any of the readXXX() on a Cursor).

BTW you might be interested in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)

Comment: I think your assumption is correct - runQuery should return a new Cursor, which means a new query against the database. I don't see how CursorAdapter is a solution for my problem - it merely defines a framework to bind data from a Cursor to a ListView.

Comment: Manually iterating Cursor is a solution, but I don't know how I can manually create a new Cursor based on data that matches the new criterion (or remove rows from an existing Cursor). Any ideas?

Comment: I still stand by the idea, that executing new query against database is a better solution. DB is designed to be queried over. Your cursor after an execution does not actually contain any data from the database (lazy loading), so it is quite harmless or it is less harmless than trying to filter existing Cursor in which case you actually read data from database to your application.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Re-querying the database is simply not fast enough. Lazy loading does not help either as I actually have to read data from each row in the cursor after executing the query, to display the results in my application. Caching the data in my own data structures yields much better performance, but I was hoping I might find a way to leverage the database and avoid data duplication.

Comment: I see. Well it is good thing you have already solved the issue even if not the way you wanted to. I'm just curious: how many records are you trying to filter?

Comment: Not many, several hundreds at most. I haven't run out of memory or anything; however, conceptually I'm not comfortable using up twice the storage space, especially  on a portable device.